# Center-left aligned equations

Tags: equations, align

I have multiple equations that I want center-aligned, but starting at the same point, like I see in other people's texts:

[image]

If I use this code:

```
\begin{align*}
\Pr(\mathbb{X}_2 = 0) = 1-\Pr(\mathbb{X}_2 > 0) \\
\Pr(\mathbb{X}_2 = 4) = \Pr(\mathbb{X}_2 > 3.99) 
\end{align*}
```

I get the equations center-aligned with all lines stopping at the same point, which looks weird. If I use this code:

```
\begin{align*}
\Pr(\mathbb{X}_2 = 0) &= 1-\Pr(\mathbb{X}_2 > 0) \\
\Pr(\mathbb{X}_2 = 4) &= \Pr(\mathbb{X}_2 > 3.99) 
\end{align*}
```

I get it left aligned:

[image]
What can I do to get it center-aligned but starting at the same point?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The second code snippet provides the same shaping as in the picture. Use `\Pr`, not `Pr`.

Comment: Thank you! But it is not centered when I run it, I'll add a new photo to the question.

Comment: Off-topic, but do not forget to define `Pr` as an operator (not italic).

Comment: Thanks, fixed the last ones too now! But could it be something weird with my file? I tried to run my friends code that was centered in her document, but then it was left aligned in mine.

Comment: Centered for me too. You should post a complete MWE - a minimal example that reproduces the problem. Start with a copy of your document and remove pieces until you find out what makes the problem go away. If it doesn't, then show the smallest example that shows it.

Comment: Are you by any chance using the option `[fleqn]`?

Comment: Yes! I removed it and now it works! Could there be any downsides of removing it? I just got the lines in the start of the document from my supervisor, don't really know what they're for.

Comment: Sorry, read about [fleqn] now. But thank you so much everyone!

Comment: @campa -- can you post an answer, please?  (i looked for a duplicate, but couldn't find one.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton done, even if I think it was a wild guess rather than a proper answer...

Comment: @campa -- even wild guesses are often good. and having an answer keeps this off the "answer the unanswered" list.  thanks.