# Center Align in a left-aligned environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, align

How do I align a particular equation to the center in a left aligned environment. I guess one benefit of left alignment is when the equations are quite long. However this question, applies in the case of a short equation in the align left environment. I use the environment below:

```
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
```

From my study, [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303172/center-left-aligned-equations) differs from the one being asked here

Comment: You can use the package `\usepackage{nccmath}`and the environement `ceqn` to center your equations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `nccmath` allow you to center your equations in a `fleqn` document, here is a quick example,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{ceqn}
\begin{align}
& e = m c^{2} \\
& c^2 = a^2 +b^2
\end{align}
\end{ceqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

It also works with a simple `equation` environment,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{ceqn}
\begin{equation}
e = m c^{2}
\end{equation}
\end{ceqn}

\end{document}
```

Hope that helps.

Romain

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can `\begin{ceqn} \end{ceqn}` be used with `\begin{equation} \end{equation}`? Currently I haven't gotten a repository to download it yet.

Comment: I have added an edit to my answer using a standard `equation` environment :-)