# align: control where equations are stretched

Tags: amsmath

I would like to format equations in a very particular way, the desired result would be:

```
        f(x)           = 42       (1)
        g_something(x) =  0       (2)
```

1. the function names are left aligned (*but the entire equations remain floating, and there is no extensive stretch*)
2. the equations are numbered (reason against `array` as [there is no easy way to add the numbers*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111898/19326)
3. the numbers are right aligned to align decimal places (**Bonus** since *currently* not an issue)

Below you find a MWE with the basic equation and me trying to achieve my alignment by adding additional `&`

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
        f(x) &= 42 \\
        g_{\text{something}}(x) &= 1
    \end{align}

    %incorrect alignment of parts
    \begin{align}
        &f(x) &= 42& \\
        &g_{\text{something}}(x) &= 1&
    \end{align}

    %too much spacing
    \begin{align}
        &f(x) &=&& 42& \\
        &g_{\text{something}}(x) &=&& 1&
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

I believe neither `fleqn` nor `nccmath` solve my issue. I came across `nccmath` in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/434090/19326) however, the `=` signs are missaligned in that answer.

* (if I understand the answer correctly)

Comment: Please not that `\text` should **never** be used to make something upright like you are doing here. It will be italic under the right circumstances, use something like `\textup` instead. This is a very common mistake.

Comment: @daleif: thank you for pointing out my mistake, do you know where I can find details about *why* this is bad?

Comment: You don't need to, try `\textit{gggg $\text{A} $ bbb} `, here A comes out italic. For something like this you want a solution that always works, that is always upright.

Comment: @daleif the following is from page 7(11 in the pdf) of [amsldoc](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf) "Line-by-line annotations on an equation can be done by judicious application of
\text inside an align environment:" so I guess, `\text` *can* be fine but one has to be aware of the drawback you pointed out.

Comment: as you can see in the example given in amsldoc, those are textual comments in displayed math. Your example is not. This is a textual subscript or a subscript using a teaxual word as a subscript (not a math variable), this needs careful typesetting as to never be confused with many math variables being multiplicated together.  This is just as wrong: `\text{Var}(X)`, again this is not a textual comment. it is a math operator and should be treated as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's  `alignat` which gives control of the spacing between columns of alignment. Here you need 3 columns, hence 5 ampersands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

    \begin{alignat}{3}
        &f(x) & & ={}& 42& \\
        &g_{\text{something}}(x) & & =& 1&
    \end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: While I noticed that `{}` is needed to fix the spacing between the `=` and `42`, I do not understand why it is needed. So far I assumed that `\begin{mathenviornment}` guranteed (more or less) proper spacing around the diferent operators, including `=`. Could you enlighten me? (I understand it as a way to place an empty token, but cant see how this helps with alignment.

Comment: I suppose that being surrounded by two `&` makes `=` ordinary math instead of `mathrel`. You have the same problem when you break a line of equation, and the second line begins with + or –: without `{}+…`, you don't get the math bin spacing.

Answer (score 2):

like this?

[image]

above system of equation is obtained by us of the `alignat` math environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{alignat}{3}
        &f(x)                    & = & 42 \\
        &g_{\text{something}}(x) & = & 1
    \end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't the spacing after the = wrong? And even if the OP used it, don't promote using `\text` like this. Plus the OP wanted the 1 under the 2

Comment: @daleif, you are right. meantime Bernard provide better solution (exploitation of the `alignat` environment ...